# How do you retain markup language in an div.html() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

What i want is allow users to be able to write markup language in an div element
So if the was a script as such, so writemarkup = .....

```
<script type="text/magicTemplate" id="scriptId">
var div = document.createElement("div"),
    span = document.createElement("span");

span.textContent = data.foo;

div.appendChild(span);

return div;
</script>
```

and i need to write this in the div.html(writemarkup);

I have tried to htmlencode all the text serverside and then write it into the .html() but the script tags go missing because the .html() actually decodes everything

```
Dim messageUrlEncoded As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(message)
```

The text is originally coming from a text area by the way

This is what im doing to write out the message

```
    var divMessage = $("<div/>");
    $(divMessageOuter).append(divMessage);
    $(divMessage).attr("class", "divmessage");
    $(divMessage).html(message);
```

The output is:

```
<script&nbsp;type="text/magicTemplate"&nbsp;id="scriptId"><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;var&nbsp;div&nbsp;=&nbsp;document.createElement("div"),<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;span&nbsp;=&nbsp;document.createElement("span");<br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;span.textContent&nbsp;=&nbsp;data.foo;<br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;div.appendChild(span);<br /><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;return&nbsp;div;<br /></script>
```

Comment: Why not use third party libralies like [Markdown Sharp](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/)?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to write into the div (escaped HTML?). Writing something like '<div></div>' into a div works just fine using .innerText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried .text() instead of .html()?

**Update:**

Have you tried using .text() without HTML encoding the output on the server first?

**Final Update**

Have you tried this?

```
$(divMessage).text(message.replace('<br />', '\r\n'));
```

Comment: .text() doesnt work as the output comes out like this &lt;script&amp;nbsp;type=&quot;text/magicTemplate&quot;&amp;nbsp;id=&quot;scriptId&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;var&amp;nbsp;div&amp;nbsp;=&amp;nbsp;document.createElement(&quot;div&quot;),&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;span&amp;nbsp;=&amp;nbsp;document.createElement(&quot;span&quot;);&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;span.textContent&amp;nbsp;=&amp;nbsp;data.foo;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;div.appendChild(span);&lt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/script&gt;

Comment: you are correct that works but the other problem is is that the line breaks dont work, i need to preserve the newlines aswell from the textarea

Comment: On the server, don't encode any HTML, but convert <br /> to \r\n. Inside a textarea, linebreaks should not be represented as <br />, but rather with plain old newline characters.

Comment: but when i do this the text comes out with <br /> rather than the line breaks, when i use .text()

Comment: BTW, I +1'd Emmanuel N's comment about using markdown or some other kind of middle man between your users' HTML and your application. What if someone submits malicious script to your app? Will you still render it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to fill the `div` using JQuery.

Comment: .text() doesnt work as the output comes out like this &lt;script&amp;nbsp;type=&quot;text/magicTemplate&quot;&amp;nbsp;id=&quot;script‌​Id&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;var&amp;nbsp;div&amp;nbsp;=&amp;nbsp;document.createEle‌​ment(&quot;div&quot;),&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&amp;‌​nbsp;span&amp;nbsp;=&amp;nbsp;document.createElement(&quot;span&quot;);&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;span.textContent&amp;nbsp;=&amp;nbsp;data.foo;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;div.appendChild(sp;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/script&gt;